# Incorrect date when converting unix epoch to human readable using Java

Tags: java, android, epoch

**EDIT:** Removed the '*1000' and still getting incorrect date but updated the log below to show what I am now getting.

Below is my code snippet and my log and I thought I implemented it correctly so I don't know why it isn't giving me the correct conversion:

```
NewFoodItem foodItem = data.get(position);
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (foodItem.date));
String a =  Integer.toString(foodItem.date);
Log.d("returnedDate:", a);
Log.d("formattedDate:", date);
```

It won't let me post an image but the log looks like this:

```
D/returnedDate:  1409012824
D/formattedDate: 01/17/1970 02:23:32
D/returnedDate:  1409013004
D/formattedDate: 01/17/1970 02:23:33
```

Comment: Why do you multiply the `date*1000`?

Comment: @arielnmz because the `returnedDate` is in second, I assumed.

Comment: Yes, seconds, not miliseconds

Comment: You need the *1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds. But all arithmeetic needs to be done as longs or you will overflow the int result and get an odd formatted date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested with some assumption, and it seems that the problem is related to **integer overflow**.

I assume you defined `NewFoodItem.date` as `int`, instead of `long`. Hence, when you multiply the `date * 1000` (both are `int`), it returns `int`.

```
int d = 1409012824; // foodItem.date
int d1000 = d * 1000; // returns 263550912 because of overflow, instead of 1409012824000

String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Date(d1000)); // returns 01/04/1970 08:42:30
```

When I try changing one of them to `long`, it behaves as expected

```
// case 1
long d = 1409012824;
long d1000 = d * 1000; // now returns 1409012824000 correctly

String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Date(d1000)); // returns 08/26/2014 08:27:04

// case 2
int d = 1409012824;
long d1000 = d * 1000L; // note the "L" suffix to indicate the number as long 
long d1000f = d * 1000; // FAIL, still returns 263550912 because of integer overflow

String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Date(d1000)); // returns 08/26/2014 08:27:04
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Date(d1000f)); // returns 01/04/1970 08:42:30
```

Generally when working with `Date` in Java, we define them as `long` since normally they are in millisecond. For easier maintenance, changing the type of `NewFoodItem.date` as `long` is the preferred one; much better if it's in millisecond also.

Comment: Perfect that was the issue.  I knew I was supposed to be using a long but I had to convert to integer because I am using SQLite and I didn't realize the int would not work when converting back to human readable.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Andrew T.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496730/642706) is correct: integer overflow. But the example code is now outmoded.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

The `Instant` class represents a moment. Like `java.util.Date`, `Instant` counts from the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. But `Instant` uses a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

Append an `L` to the end of your numeric literal to indicate `long` type. Use underscores wherever you like to group your digits, with no meaning added (ignored by compiler).

```
long input = 1_409_012_824L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( input ) ;
```

Generate a textual representation of the value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2014-08-26T00:27:04Z

For more flexibility in generating text, convert to a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Automatically localize the output using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output2 = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> Aug 26, 2014, 12:27:04 AM

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UlKmP3).

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).